# Algorithm: check whether the summation of n random numbers is equal to integer K?

Tags: algorithm, sum, double, random

We have n random numbers which is less than 1.0 and greater than 0 i.e. 0.0 < a_i < 1.0 .

**How  to check whether there exist a set S which contains elements of property a_i such that summation of all a_i is equal to a integer constant K where i=1,2,...,n ?**

Note: set should contain n elements.

e.g.

1. N = 4 and K = 2 then 
   we can choose {0.5 ,0.5 ,0.5 ,0.5} or {0.25 ,0.75 ,0.5 ,0.5} since their sum is 2 so  answer is yes .
2. N = 4 and K = 4 then answer is no since we can't choose a_i such that their sum K = 4 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            B1-1<A1 <= B1
            B2-1<A2 <= B2
            B3-1<A3 <= B3
            ........
            ........
            Bn-1<An <= Bn

            n => Total number of elements.
```

Summing (as we do in 10th standard :) :)  )

I think there is no need of writting pseudo-code for sum=B1+B2+...+Bn :)

```
            sum-n < K(given) <= sum-n<K-sum <= 0
```

This condition is equivalent to (K+n>sum) && (sum>=K)

I hope, you gotcha!

Comment: @john, My answer is correct for the given question.This is a ultimate hint.May be your question is different!!!